# Looking for an effecient way to compare points and areas in time series data with multiple independent variables

Tags: r, function, time-series, workflow, average

If you know of an example data set that would be useful in answering this question it is welcome.
Suppose I have a data frame that is structured like this:

```r
>data
  ID  Location Sex   Time Copper Iron  Carbon  Mg   Lead  CaCO3
   12     A     M     1    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     2    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     3    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     4    …      …     …     …     …     …
   12     A     M     5    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     6    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     1    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     2    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     3    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     4    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     5    …      …     …     …     …     …
```

There are several hundred individuals, each having a unique ID number. The concentration of each element or substance (Copper, Iron, Carbon, Mg, Lead, CaCO3) is measured every second for an amount of time that is unique to each individual. So in the real data there are several hundred measurements per individual. For instance in the example above there are only 6 observations for individual 12, and 5 observations for individual 234. In reality individual 12 may have 980 observations and individual 234 may have 1249 observations.

Due to the nature of these measurements, the concentration of each substance should be the same (or very similar) at the start and end for each individual. For instance if individual 12 has 980 observations, the concentration of `Copper` in the first several observations (time 1:n) should be similar to the last several observations (n:980), and this is true for all of the substances. To test this hypothesis, and get an idea of how long (or how many data points) the substances remain similar on either end of the series, I want to conduct paired t-tests between the first observation and the average of the first 5 observations, first observation and the last observation, the average of the first 5 observations and the average of the last 5 observations, and the same for the average of the first and last 7 and 10 observations, ect...

What is the best way to tackle this problem? This is how I started to go about it:

First save the value for each point of interest (the first point, the average of the first 7 points, ect..) in separate data frames:

```r
#examples shown for the first point, and the average of the first 7 points:
#get the first data point for each individual:
FirstPt<-
  data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  slice(1)
FirstPt <-
  FirstPt%>%
  pivot_longer(Copper:CaCO3, names_to = "Variable")
FirstPt <- as.data.frame(FirstPt)
#repeat for the last data point replace slice(1) with slice(n())

#get the average of the first 7 data points for each individual:
First7avg<-
data%>%
  pivot_longer(Copper:CaCO3, names_to = "Variable")%>%
  group_by(ID,Location,Sex, Variable)%>%
  top_n(7, desc(Time))%>%
  summarize(Average = mean(value))
First7avg$Average <- round(First7avg$Average, 2)
First7avg <- as.data.frame(First7avg)
#repeat for the last 7 data points but replace top_n(7,desc(Time)) with top_n(7, Time)%>%
```

I then combined each data set so that it is structured like this:

```r
ID      Variable   FirstPt  LastPt  First5Avg Last5Avg First7Avg Last7Avg First10Avg Last10Avg  
12      Copper     
12      Iron     
12      Carbon     
12       Mg      
12      Lead     
12      CaCO3     
234     Copper    
234     Iron     
234     Carbon     
234      Mg      
234     Lead      
234     CaCO3
```

Then I began to create objects that held the numbers I wanted to compare:

```r
#make comparisons grouping all 6 substances by individual:
FirstPtvsLastPt <- dplyr::select(data,c(ID,FirstPt,LastPt))

FirstPtvsLastPt%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarise(ttest = t.test(FirstPt, LastPt, paired = T)$p.value)

First7AvgvsLast7Avg <- dplyr::select(data,c(ID,First7Avg,Last7Avg))

First7AvgvsLast7Avg%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarise(ttest = t.test(First7Avg, Last7Avg, paired = T)$p.value)
```

I repeated this for each comparison. I realize this part is a discussion for another forum, but for transparency in the question I want to answer I will explain; Next, instead of comparing the observations of all 6 substances within each individual, I used `Location` as a grouping variable (there are several `Locations` the individuals can be grouped into) and made the same comparisons (the first point vs the average of the first 7 points, ect..) within individual substances:

```r
#example compares the concentration of Mg in the first point and last point
Mg_FirstPtvsLastPt <-
  data%>%
  filter(Variable == "Mg")%>%
  select(c(Location, FirstPt,LastPt))

Mg_FirstPtvsLastPt%>%
  group_by(Location)%>%
  summarise(ttest = t.test(FirstPt, LastPt, paired = T)$p.value)
```

At this point I have done a lot of copying and pasting and created a ton of new objects, each with a similar name. I am beginning to worry about the human-error associated with this repetitive work flow, but I don't know a better way to do it. At the end, I would combine all of the p-values into a single data frame next to the test (or comparison) they are associated with. What is a more efficient, and faster way to go about doing this? Can it be done using the original dataset so that I don't have to create so many new objects? Possibly with a user-written function?